# is it possible to convert .jasper into .jrxml?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I accidently ended up corrupting my .jrxml file but fortunately before that I had a working .jasper version of the same file. Is there anyway to kind of reverse the .jasper to retrieve my .jrxml? I spent almost whole day today to format my report and all of sudden it's gone. Would really appreciate any ideas.

**Edits:**

I am using iReport 3.1.1 and I don't see any option of converting to .jrxml when I am opening the .jasper file. Do I need a higher or a different version to be able to do this conversion?

Comment: Have u got any idea ,how these files getting corrupted suddenly?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use the create a.JRXML file using compiled .Jasper file, to generate .JRXML file in iReport open  .Jasper file , it automatically generate a .JRXML file for the same .Jasper file and then you can generate report.

Comment: Does it depend upon iReport version? I am using version 3.1.1 and when I try to open .jasper it's not asking me if I need to convert it into .jrxml? The popup message that I get when I open is "This file appears to contain binary data. Are you sure want to open it inthe text editor?".

Answer (score 2):

If you try to open a .jasper file with iReport, it will ask you if you want to convert it into a .jrxml file first. This way the decompilation process will be handled automatically:

[image]

Comment: getting Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: net.sf.jasperreports.crosstabs.base.JRBaseCrosstabGroup; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6144263542628036271, local class serialVersionUID = 7685014062058258277