# How to convert .jasper to .jrxml?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have few .jasper files where I do not have the .jrxml files. Now, I need to edit these jasper files. I only have to remove an image in them.

I tried lot of solutions, trying almost every link in [here](https://www.google.lk/search?q=decompile%20jasper%20to%20jrxml&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enLK494LK494&oq=howto%20decompile%20jasper%20to%20jrxml&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.12973j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). However the "convert" code solutions provided different posts are very old and no longer correct.

I do have Jaspersoft studio community edition too, where I originally used to generate the .jasper from .jrxml.

can someone please explain me how to convert .jasper to .jrxml without issues? Even without a conversation, if I can directly edit the items I need from .jasper, that is also fine.

Comment: have a look at this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666096/is-it-possible-to-convert-jasper-into-jrxml

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala: I am not using `IReoport`, which is the netbeans plugin for Jasper reports.